# Update values from another table with same parent and child

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: Table1 and Table2 which have following data:

```
 Table1                              Table2
 Parent 123,456,1111                   Parent 123,456,1111
 Child  1111,2222,4567                 Child  1111,9999,4567
 ANS    0,0 ,0                           Code  aaa,bbb,ccc
```

If there are same parent and child in table2, update the `ANS` in Table1 to `1` else remains as `0`.The `0` is default.Parent and child are primary keys.The child  can be parent of another child in both table.

```
UPDATE table1 SET ANS='1' FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 SET ANS='1' 
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b 
ON a.parent = b.parent and a.child = b.child
```

Comment: I tried but the ANS changed all to 1 no matter same parent and child.

Comment: u r format is like  this only ri8 : row1: 1,b,0 row2: 2,f,0 row1: 1,b,123 row2: 2,e,456

Comment: Format is the same.They are a lot more.The child in table2 can be parent of another child in table2.

Comment: that is not a problem : parent and child should match that is what u want ri8?

Comment: Yes.In order to update, the parent and child should be same for both tables.

Comment: the above code is not working ... Can u give me an instance where this is failing

Comment: you do not want to update data where child who is also  parent ?

Comment: For example, the output of ANS in table1 should be 1,0,1

Comment: that is how u will get the output ri8

Comment: hey i tried the same query with the data given it worked for me as u said 1,0,1.. can u check ur self again

Comment: Found the mistake.Thanks.